# GetModuleFileNameEx is returning 0 and GetLastError returns Overflow error. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: c++, windows

So today I decided to mess a bit with windows.h and I thought of a little exercise to practise, this is the code I wrote, but it's giving me headaches.

It keeps returning 0, so no name is being passed into ExecName, and the error I get if I lookup with GetLastError() is Overflow error.

I've tried different methods of getting the executables' names but it always ends the same.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <Psapi.h>

TCHAR* ExeToFind = "Discord.exe";

BOOL CALLBACK CB_EW(
    _In_ HWND   hwnd,
    _In_ LPARAM lParam
)
{
    TCHAR ExecName[MAX_PATH];
    DWORD ProcesID = NULL;

    GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, &ProcesID);
    HANDLE handle = OpenProcess(NULL, false, ProcesID);
    if (GetModuleFileNameEx(handle, NULL, ExecName, MAX_PATH) == 0) {
        std::cout << "Error " << GetLastError();
        return true;
    }

    //GetWindowText(hwnd, ExecName, GetWindowTextLength(hwnd)+1);
    //GetProcessImageFileName(hwnd, ExecName, MAX_PATH);


    std::cout << ExecName;
    if (ExecName == ExeToFind) {

        std::cout << "Here it is\n";
        return false;
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "next\n";
        return true;
    }
}


int main()
{
    //HWND hWnd = FindWindow(0,0);

    EnumWindows(CB_EW, NULL);

    while (true) {

    }
    return 0;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `DWORD ProcesID[sizeof(DWORD)];` is almost certainly not what you meant to write.

Comment: Thank you, didn't even notice, just changed it but it still ends to the same result

Comment: Ok, so now I added errorcheck for the OpenProcess return and I get an access denied error

Comment: the `GetModuleFileNameEx` is wrong api here - you need use `GetProcessImageFileName` or `QueryFullProcessImageName`. and need open process handle with `PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION` on xp only or `PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION` access right

Answer (score 0):

It was a permission issue, instead of using NULL for the access permission on OpenProcess, I used MAXIMUM_ALLOWED and it worked

Comment: instead `MAXIMUM_ALLOWED` need understand what access you need and ask exactly this access

Comment: Thanks, I've now used `PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION`

Comment: `PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION` you need use only on xp/2003. begin from vista need use `PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION`